# gazebo or v-rep for ros integration

Tags: simulation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi i would like to know the the difference between gazebo and v-rep for simulation and the pros and cons of each if possible

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237419/gazebo-or-v-rep-for-ros-integration/) by [rajnunes](https://answers.ros.org/users/26472/rajnunes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2016-06-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Having experienced with both gazebo and v-rep for a small amount of time, I think that gazebo is by far the better choice in terms of ease of use, ros integration capabilities and documentation. v-rep has a vast variety of ready to use robots and has more options than gazebo (at least gazebo 5 that I have used) when it comes to simulations but apart from that integrating with ros is not considered to be a trivial task.

---

Originally posted by [bergercookie](https://answers.ros.org/users/25299/bergercookie/) with karma: 257 on 2016-10-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4